# How to program to have all processors on your machine used?

Tags: python, windows, processor

I am running a single-threaded python program that performs massive data processing on my windows box. My machine has 8 processors. When I monitor the CPU usage in performance tab under Windows Task Manager, it shows that I am using only a very small fraction of the processing power available to me. Only one processor is being used to the fullest and all the rest are almost idle. What should I do to ensure that all my processors are used? Is multithreading a solution?

Comment: Yes multithreading is required.

Comment: but without a description  of your program we can't say if or how

Comment: No multithreading is not a required.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

multithreading cannot make use of extra processors or cores.

You should spawn new processes instead of new threads.

This tool is by far the simplest among all that I have come across:
[parallel python](http://www.parallelpython.com)

> Overview:
>
> PP is a python module which provides mechanism for parallel
>   execution of python code on SMP
>   (systems with multiple processors or
>   cores) and clusters (computers
>   connected via network).
>
> It is light, easy to install and integrate with other python software.
>
> PP is an open source and cross-platform module written in pure
>   python

Comment: I simplified my reply alot. The context is of course, coding with Python, so it has the limitations that you and others have mentioned.

Comment: @Forest: You should review http://us.pycon.org/2010/conference/schedule/event/76/ and then reconsider the commonly held (usually wrong) wisdom that some threading can be efficient even with the GIL.  The GIL has some truly unusual practical effects that defy what you might imagine the theory to be.

Comment: (Also of course keep in mind that we're talking about CPython here - other implementations have robust concurrency support while using threads)

Comment: @user496852 does it not work with python 3.1? i tried installing PP on my machine which uses python 3.1..setup complained that it didn't find a python installation directory in registry and stalled at that stage

Comment: although the site says it supports py2.3+, I doubt it works on py3.0+ But your problem sounds like an installation issue. Have you installed Python correctly? It should have created an entry in Windows registery. Do try Py2.x if in doubt.

Answer (score 2):

Multithreading is required for a single process, but it is not necessarily a solution; processor affinity can restrict it to a subset of available cores even if you have more than enough threads to use all.

Comment: Do you really mean "it is not a solution" or "it *might* not be a solution"? Will processor affinity *definitely* be an issue?

Comment: Great, thanks. Makes a lot more sense. I was wondering whether there was some handicap within Python which would cause problems.

Comment: @Jon: Well, there is, but the GIL is a separate issue.

Answer (score 2):

you can get that if your program is of the type that would benefit using [python's multiprocessing module](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html)

multiprocessing uses multiple python process which avoids problems with the GIL so it's possible to use all of those cores with python code it has a easy threaded map and the basis for more complex schemes

it is similar to parallel python but is limited to the local machine and is included with python 2.6 and higher and is metaphorically similar to python's threading

Comment: Please expand on your answer. I don't understand what you're trying to say.

Answer (score 2):

As an addition to what Jon said, if you're using the standard Python interpreter you should understand the limitations with respect to multi-threading. If your threads are pure-python and aren't making system calls, they can't run concurrently on multiple processors due to the [Global Interpreter Lock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Interpreter_Lock) so the benefits to multi-threading are minimal. In this case, perhaps the recommendation would be to go with multiple processes instead or to switch to another Python implementation such as JPython or IronPython, which do not have a Global Interpreter Lock.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your task *is* parallelizable, then yes, threading is certainly a solution. In particular, if you have a lot of data items to process but they can all be handled *independently* then it should be relatively straightforward to parallelize.

Using multiple processes instead of multiple threads *might* be another solution - you haven't told us enough about the problem to say, really.

Comment: in fact multiple processes *is* the most generic solution, since spreading multiple threads of the same process over multiple cores might not be supported on a given platform/OS.

Comment: @knitti: The question is about Windows specifically. There are plenty of times where using multiple processes would be inconvenient to the point of infeasibility where threads wouldn't be too bad.

Comment: sorry, I obviously must hone my reading skills... but out of curiosity: why do you think multiple processes would be that inconvenient?

Answer (score 1):

Do this.

Break your task in to steps or stages.  Each step reads something, does part of the overall calculation and writes something.

```
"""Some Step."""
import json
for some_line in sys.stdin:
    object= json.loads( some_line )
    # process the object
    json.dump( result, sys.stdout )
```

Something like that ought to do fine.

If you have multiple objects that must be communicated, make a simple dictionary of the objects.

```
results = { 'a': a, 'b': b }
```

Connect them in a pipeline, like this.

```
python step1.py | python step2.py | python step3.py >output_file.dat
```

If you can break things into 8 or more steps, you will use 8 or more cores.  And, BTW, this will be blazingly fast for very little real work.